# Convert string to byte ("exact" conversion)

Tags: python

I have a string in Python 3.x like:

```
command = '\x66\x08\x01\x01\x01\x04\x00\xff\xff\x04'
```

Now I need a function `f` that converts to bytes, so that

```
f(command) = b'\x66\x08\x01\x01\x01\x04\x00\xff\xff\x04'
```

`encode('utf-8')` does not work:

```
>>> command.encode('utf-8') == b'\x66\x08\x01\x01\x01\x04\x00\xff\xff\x04'
False
```

Comment: The byte sequence can not be represented as a string. Try `print(command)`, you will see that the value is incorrect before you even try any conversion

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili they have already tried that... wrapping the return value of `.encode()` in `bytes` does not change anything.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Using encoding 'latin-1' does the trick. Thanks!! Would have searched ages.